# Django DecimalField generating "quantize result has too many digits for current context" error on save

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal

I've got a model like:

```
class ModelWithDecimal(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=2)
```

...yet when I try...

```
obj = ModelWithDecimal(value="1.5")
obj.save()
```

I get a `quantize result has too many digits for current context` error during the save. Shouldn't that be OK - it's less than 2 digits, and less than 2 digits after the decimal-point?

The same error happens with a model:

```
class ModelWithDecimal(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=8)
```

...and attempted instance...

```
obj = ModelWithDecimal(value="1005.7")
obj.save()
```

Again, seems it should work: only 4 total digits (less than 11), and only 1 after decimal (less than 8).

What's wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that all the right-of-the-decimal `decimal_places` are consumed by every instance, regardless of whether you have non-zero digits there, leaving only `(max_digits - decimal_places)` digits for left-of-the-decimal.

So for `DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=2)`, there's room for *zero* digits to the left of the decimal, and "1.5" won't fit. And for `DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=8)`, there's room for only *three* digits to the left of the decimal, and "1005.7" won't fit.

Expand your `max_digits` and the values will work.